# Problem with displaying data (nuxt3 + tauri + prisma)

Tags: frontend, desktop-application, prisma, nuxtjs3, tauri

I am a newbie and i have a problem with displaying data from the database on the front-end. I'm working on a desktop app. I tried different methods, but I didn't solve the problem (maybe I missed something)
I have problem to display data on front-end.

- initialize Prisma Client on /lib/prsima.d.ts
- use defineEventHandler() and useFech()
  At the moment I was just trying to display the data.

#### **/server/api/sim.get.ts**

```
import prisma from "~/lib/prisma"

export default defineEventHandler(async (_event) => {
const mit = await prisma.simowie.findMany(); 
return mit 
})
```

## **src/lib/prisma.d.ts**

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';let prisma: PrismaClient;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
prisma = new PrismaClient();
} 
else {
let globalWithPrisma = global as typeof globalThis & {prisma: PrismaClient;
};

if (!globalWithPrisma.prisma) {globalWithPrisma.prisma = new PrismaClient();}prisma = globalWithPrisma.prisma;}export default prisma;
```

## src/pages/table.vue

```
<template>
    <SideBarMini class="flex fixed"/>
    <div class="flex h-screen w-screen justify-center items-center ">
            <div > {{abc}} </div>
    </div>
</template>
    

<script setup>

    async function abcs(){
            return await useFetch("/api/sim")
    }

    const abc = ref(null)
    abc.value =   abcs()
       

</script>
```